# Angular2 + Formspree. Bad request 400

Tags: angular, email

I'm trying to implement a contact form by using [formspree.io](http://formspree.io) in an 'angular2+' application. As I don't want to handle http requests directly from my component, I created a contact service for doing this job.
Unfortunately it seems my request is not posted properly:

> status:400 (bad request) {   "error": "Can't send an empty form" }

here my code:

**contact.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



    @Injectable()
    export class ContactService {

      constructor(private http: Http) { 

      }

         postEmail(name: String, email: String, message: String): Observable<string>{

          let headers = new Headers({ 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

          });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

          let url = "http://formspree.io/my@email.com";
          let data = {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message
          }

          return this.http.post(url, data, options)
          .map(response => {
            console.log('email sent', response);
            return response;
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
        }

      private handleError(err){
            //error handling
        }


    }
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Contact } from './contact.interface';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    emailForm: FormGroup;
    messageSentSuccess: boolean;
  messageSentError: boolean;
    events: any[]=[];

  constructor(
    private service: ContactService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder
    ) { 

    this.emailForm = this._fb.group({
      'email':   [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'name':    [null, Validators.required ],
      'message': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)])]
    });


  }

  onSubmit(form: any) {
      this.service.postEmail(form.value.name.toString(),form.value.email.toString(),form.value.message.toString())
      .map(res => res)
      .subscribe(
        res => {},
        error => {
                  this.messageSentError = true;
                  this.emailForm.reset();
                  setTimeout(()=>{this.messageSentError=false},3000);
                  },
        () => {
          this.messageSentSuccess=true;
          setTimeout(()=> { this.messageSentSuccess=false },3000);
         }
      );
    }

}
```

Comment: can you check if the form data is getting printed in console

Comment: the data that is being send is evaluating to null

Comment: the form data is correctly submitted, meaning that the variable  name, email, are message have validated inputs (I xchecked in console)

Comment: can you please post the code where you are calling the service method

Comment: @RahulSingh , done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting with the team of formspree.io, I found out that after submission  sends its data serialized. 
As my service is sending my "data" in form of a json file which cannot be computed by the formspree backend.Thus I simply rewrited the "data" attribute, using ES6, in a serialized form.

Here the code:

```
 postEmail(name: String, email: String, message: String): Observable<string>{

      let headers = new Headers({ 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

      });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      let url = "http://formspree.io/my@email.com";

      // WRONG
      // let data = {
      //   name: name,
      //   email: email,
      //   message: message
      // }

      // RIGHT
      let data = `name=${name}&email=${email}&message=${message}`;

      return this.http.post(url, _data, options)
      .map(response => {
        console.log('email sent', response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }

  private handleError(err){
        // handle error
    }
```

And it works!

Comment: What is RequestOptions?

Comment: ```import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';```